# Adding users to system

Tags: linux

I usually add a user using adduser command. But are there any other steps to add a user to a system without using useradd/adduser?
how can we change the default uid range?

Comment: Three off-topic votes so far. What is off topic about this question?

Comment: For what purpose? Why does adduser not meet your requirements? What are these requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your distribution, as each has their own little niggles.  On Debian, for instance, `adduser` is just a perl script that calls various underlying utilities like `useradd`, `usermod`, `chage`, and makes the home directory and copies `/etc/skel` into place -- all things you can do yourself if you need to.  Even calling `adduser` is unnecessary, if you're willing to edit `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and so on yourself.

To address your second question (which should be a separate one), to modify the default UID range used on a Debian system you should edit `/etc/adduser.conf`, specifically the `FIRST_UID` and `LAST_UID` values, taking care not to overlap with other ranges.